# Problem with the property of gamma function

Tags: number-theory

I know that $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(\overline{z})$ Is a real number. But is $\Gamma(-z)\Gamma(\overline{z})$ also a real number  ?

Answer (score 2):

Does not give real results:

```
? f(z) = gamma(-z)*gamma(conj(z))
%14 = (z)->gamma(-z)*gamma(conj(z))
? f(I)
%15 = -0.22401015640061193977336138045606478672 - 0.15433488453310160491802080602790582315*I
```